# Creating an online mySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Is it possible to make an mySQL database on the web so that any person from any network can access it? For example if somebody in Europe downloads my program, it will still be able to connect to the mySQL database without problems.

Currently, I am using Connector J with a locally hosted mySQL database.

**Edit**: Basically I want to create an online mySQL database (not locally hosted) where anybody can download my program and the program from any internet connection can read and write the data from the server online.

Also are there any free online mySQL hosting services?

**Edit**:
For example, java games access data online from a database, but they are not on the same database. How can I achieve this? Are mySQL databases still the way to go?

Comment: Yes, it is. Look into grant and privileges in the mysql manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand your purpose but what I perceived from your question is maybe you are looking for some sort of cloud app service like [Heroku](http://heroku.com). Take a look at their [ClearDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb) add-on and see if that fulfills your need.

[This was supposed to be a comment but due to the lack of my Reputation points I have to submit it as an answer]